# File not found expedition when trying to access a list in SharePoint

Tags: list

I am an absolute newbie to please excuses my stupidity :)

Using Visual studios (c#), I have an windows form that has a button on it that when prompt it execute code that adds a new item to an SP list called "WebServiceExercise". But the code does not want to take my url. The list is sitting on my Team site. I am doing this server side. Its might be a namespace issue. (only name space I added was using Microsoft.SharePoint;)

i have tried different urls but always get the File not found expedition. Please help.

here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace UpdateListDevTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SPSite mySite = new SPSite("http://MSNDev-25/sites/Jerry"))
            {
                using (SPWeb myWeb = mySite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList contactsList = myWeb.Lists["WebServiceExercise"];

                    SPListItem newItem = contactsList.Items.Add();

                    newItem["Name"] = "Test1";

                    newItem["Description"] = "This is the first test to check if I can add item to a list";

                    newItem.Update();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

myWeb.Lists["..."] expects the Title for the SPList which may be different from the Name (aka URL part) for that List if you renamed it afterwards.

If you want to get a list by the URL you can do **myWeb.GetList(url)**.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlist.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would say you have the wrong settings for your Forms application.

In the project settings (Right click the project in Visual Studio and click Properties) navigate to `Build` and set `Platform target` to `"Any CPU"`

[MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407621%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi it was on Any CPU I changed it to 64bit to check if that worked but no luck.

Comment: Also under Debug, make sure it uses the Active (Debug) configuration, with platform Active (Any CPU)

Comment: and, if this is 2010, you need to set Target framework (under Application) to .NET Framework 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Do you set all necessary settings to use sharepoint dll in windows forms like it is descriped here http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/566370/Developing-Sharepoint-Windows-Forms?